# Lua callback function does not work with table

Tags: lua

I am trying to change Xadow's baudrate of Uart and trying to do same thing on software PDF but everytime i get errors.  I just need to know how should I write the syntax.
[Here is the guide of the lua software on xadow's writer](https://ibb.co/0CNxrdK)

```
config={}
config["bit"]=9
config["par"]=0
config["stop"]=1
config["bdr"]=9600

function uartData(uart_id,len,data)
print(data)
end

uart_id=uart.create(1,uartData(config))
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> uart_id = uart.create(port, cb_func [,param])
> ```

Param is an optional Lua table as described in the documentation.

You have to call:

```
uart_id = uart.create(1, uartData, config)
```

not

```
uart_id = uart.create(1, uartData(config))
```

`uartData(config)` would pass the return value of `uartData` (`nil`) to `uart.create` instead of the function variable `uartData`

You can simply wirte `config.bit=9` instead of `config["bit"]=9` btw.

Comment: Thanks you so much for help. I tried as you did but I get error at below :

`attempt to index a function value
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'create'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
`
Screenshot of it:
[link](https://ibb.co/S6P5GRd)

Comment: PFD of the software is:
https://github.com/loboris/RePhone_on_Linux/blob/master/Documents/Lua%20on%20RePhone%20Manual.pdf